# LAN unstable connection, WIFI works

Tags: networking, ip, wifi, ethernet, dhcp

I just got a cubox-i4 but have a big problem with the LAN connection. It establishes and crashes again. The thing is, that if I connect it via LAN to an Airport Express (connected via wifi), the connection is stable (=> no hardware problem). Direct Connection to the router is not working. Here is the log when connected to the router:

```
May  8 23:45:29 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Down
May  8 23:45:30 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May  8 23:45:30 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 100/Full
May  8 23:45:36 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Half
May  8 23:45:38 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:46:00 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Half
May  8 23:46:02 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:46:24 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
May  8 23:46:24 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Down
May  8 23:46:25 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May  8 23:46:25 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 100/Full
May  8 23:46:33 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
May  8 23:46:33 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Down
May  8 23:46:35 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May  8 23:46:35 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:46:39 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Half
May  8 23:46:41 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:46:45 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Half
May  8 23:46:47 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:47:09 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
May  8 23:47:09 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Down
May  8 23:47:11 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May  8 23:47:11 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:47:15 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Half
May  8 23:47:19 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:47:23 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
May  8 23:47:23 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Down
May  8 23:47:24 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May  8 23:47:24 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
May  8 23:47:28 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
May  8 23:47:28 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Down
May  8 23:47:30 linaro-ubuntu-desktop NetworkManager[2552]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
May  8 23:47:30 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 100/Full
May  8 23:47:46 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Half
May  8 23:47:48 linaro-ubuntu-desktop kernel: PHY: 1:04 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to take an 100 mbit port, then it works!